# Height of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have written code for calculating the height of a BST, but it's giving me the wrong answer. The result is 3 but I am expecting it to be 4. Can anyone point out the flaw in my logic, please? (I'm defining the height of leaf nodes to be zero, thus height = edge count).

```
public static int getHeight(Node root){
    if(root == null || (root.right == null && root.right == null)) return 0;
    int leftHeight = getHeight(root.left);
    int rightHeight = getHeight(root.right);
    return 1 + ((leftHeight >= rightHeight) ? leftHeight : rightHeight);
}
```

The elements are added in an empty BST in the following order:

```
20, 50, 35, 44, 9, 15, 62, 11, 13
```

So I expect that it should look like this:

```
     20
   /    \
  /      \
 9        50
  \      /  \
   15   35   62
  /      \
11       44
  \
   13
```

Edit: Found the bug. I had written

```
    (root.right == null && root.right == null)
```

instead of

```
    (root.left == null && root.right == null)
```

Thanks to Peter Hall for pointing it out.

Comment: Can't you show the BST in its cascaded form? Are you sure the insertion is done correctly?

Comment: Is your spacebar broken?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, the insertion is done correctly, I've checked every other part of the code one by one.The only flaw must be in this block.

Comment: This is a simple error in the first line. You are checking if `right == null` AND `right == null`. You probably intended for one of those to be `left`.

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks, Sir. I was scratching my head over this problem for quite a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple typo. You are checking for `right == null` twice, when you almost certainly meant `left == null` for one of them.

I.e. this condition:

```
if(root == null || (root.right == null && root.right == null)) return 0;
```

Should be:

```
if(root == null || (root.right == null && root.left == null)) return 0;
```

Which will give you the answer you want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug.